# What is the name for following grammar structure:

Tags: grammar, american-english

does somebody know the name of these English grammar sentences?

"…how are hot passion and cool judgment **to be forced together** in a single soul?"

This sentence structure is similar to say: "This task needs to be done"

The second sentence is:

"Some politicians pretend **to be helping** lower-middle classes"

This is similar to the "I'm looking forward *to visiting* my mistress"

I know that it does not make sense to say "Some politicians pretend to help…".

I would like to know the name of these English grammar rules so as to understand when to use them appropriately, as I am not a native English speaker. I would be grateful if you can tell me the specific names of these rules or recommend a book where I can find them.

Comment: Do you mean "to-infinitive"? Any English phrase with "to" + the base form of a verb is called "to-infinitive". Your first sentence has a *passive* to-infinitive. Your second has a *continuous* to-infinitive. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Why do you say *it does not make sense to say "Some politicians pretend to help…"*? There's nothing at all wrong with that construction, and as [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pretend+to+help%2Cpretend+to+be+helping&year_start=1840&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows, it's *far* more common than the semantically equivalent mouthful ***pretend to be helping***.

Comment: Actually, your first sentence has a similar structure to "the task *is* to be done," not "needs to be done." There is a difference: "is to be" means "is going to be/is planned to be/will be"